# How to do conditional import in Python?

Tags: python

For example, in my test.py:

```
from .segmenter import Segmenter
```

However, this Segmenter may have been imported by another file when used in another way. How to test if Segmenter already exists in the scope, then don't import it?

Comment: No need, all imports are cached. Importing again is almost free.

Comment: But in my project, this import will automatically trigger the creation of the object, Segmenter, which cause my double creation problems in some cases. And that's why I want to find a way to check the existence of the object.

Comment: You can use try/except. the program will crash it wasn't imported. try to apply a function from `segmenter` and if it crashed import it.

Comment: @NirF So in the except block, simply use 'pass' to do nothing?

Comment: @marlon no it won't, because the module initialization is skipped after the first import.

Comment: Like @MarkRansom said, imports are cached. Your object won’t be created again. (Also, consider not having import side-effects and using a function instead.)

Comment: I depend on other's library and the library is designed such a way to be initialization so I can't change it. But the try...except seems to work for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use `dir()`, which returns a list of all names in the local scope. Something like the expression `"Segmenter" in dir()` should suffice.

```
if "Segmenter" not in dir():
  from .segmenter import Segmenter
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, it's unwise to have imports do anything other than just be imported.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a try/except block like so:

```
try:
    Segmenter
except NameError:
    from .segmenter import Segmenter
```